# Retrieving the uncertainty of a vertex in g2o

Tags: ros, vslam, g2o

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am manipulating the tutorial_slam2d example in the g2o package.  I would like to output the marginal uncertainty of each vertex.  However, using the following code snippet produces results that don't look right:

```
SparseOptimizer optimizer;
...
ofstream g2oOptResults;  
string g2oFileID = "g2oResults__" + fileID + ".txt";
 
g2oOptResults.open(g2oFileID.c_str());

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{  
VertexSE2* testPose = dynamic_cast<VertexSE2*>(optimizer.vertex(i)); 
Matrix<double,3,3> uncertainty = testPose->uncertainty();

g2oOptResults << uncertainty << endl;  
g2oOptResults << " " << endl;
}

g2oOptResults.close();
```

The problem is the returned matrix clearly cannot represent a covariance matrix; it is not symmetric.  As a typical example I get:

0.325765,  0.919874,   0.919874
-0.00215401, 0.00202767, 0.00202767
0.0196631, 0.00424371, 0.00424371

The values look like they might belong to a symmetric matrix (i.e. I get three unique values and three pairs of identical values).  They are just not arranged correctly.

Any thoughts?

Edit: on a related note, the vertices in optimizer (instance of SparseOptimizer) have an uncertainty associated with them *before* optimization.  It doesn't seem that should happen; I don't tell optimizer anything about uncertainty in the vertices, just the fixed edges.

(Sorry this is so lengthy)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39175/retrieving-the-uncertainty-of-a-vertex-in-g2o/) by [jcm76](https://answers.ros.org/users/2876/jcm76/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jcm76](https://answers.ros.org/users/2876/jcm76/) on 2012-07-19**:
Eric, could you specify what you mean by "this"?  What part is it you mean has been removed?  The whole tutorial_slam2d?  A specific method of one of the classes?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-19**:
Ah sorry for being unclear. I meant the uncertainty associated with a given vertex (which is the entire focus of your question). I could find no mention of it when I looked through the current development version. No uncertainty() member and I didn't see the uncertainty marginalization functionality

**Comment by [jcm76](https://answers.ros.org/users/2876/jcm76/) on 2012-07-19**:
Alright, so I see that the uncertainty() method doesn't exist in the github version...  The version available from https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vslam/trunk/g2o points back to the OpenSLAM.org version, which they describe as stable.  Anyone guess when is the next stable release?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-19**:
No idea. You may want to email one of people working on that Github for more info.

**Comment by [aamir](https://answers.ros.org/users/21054/aamir/) on 2015-01-08**:
Hi jcm76, Did you ever get an answer regarding this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems to have been removed from the current development versions of g2o here: https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o so perhaps there are bugs with the version of g2o ROS is using?

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1